# Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running the following:

```
var token = document.location.href.split('?s=')[1].match(/[a-z0-9]+/);
var longString = "?s=" + token + "?_sft_category=";
var tokenB = document.location.href.split(longString)[1].match(/[a-z0-9]+/);
var attribuB = "." + tokenB;
jQuery('a[data-filter-value="' + attribuB + '"]').parent().parent().parent().find(".dropdown-toggle").html(tokenB).append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
```

How come I get?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
```

If I remove `.match(/[a-z0-9]+/)` i don't get any error, but I do need `match` ..

The URL looks like:

```
http://www.example.com/xchanges/results/?s=sky&_sft_category=ogilvy
```

Comment: the error is saying 'document.location.href.split(longString)[1]' doesnt exist. what does console.log(document.location.href.split(longString)); give you

Comment: ["http://www.example.com/xchanges/results/?s=sky&_sft_category=ogilvy"]
?s=sky&_sft_category=ogilvy

Comment: so it does exists, it is like it doesn't exist if i use match

Comment: @rob.m - no it doesn't exist, you are using `?` twice in `longString`, change it to: `var longString = "?s=" + token + "&_sft_category=";`. The `?` character should only be used once, at the start of the querystring.

Comment: @Cyclone thanks a lot! I haven't noticed it had an &, damn! Could you insert that as an answer and I will accept it? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `?` twice in `longString`, which in turn will make `split()` return an array with only one value. You need to change it to:

```
var longString = "?s=" + token + "&_sft_category=";
```

The `?` character should only be used once, at the start of the querystring.

Answer (score 3):

Probably using a library would be better here. I developed a tiny JavaScript library that work with the urls: [`url.js`](https://github.com/jillix/url.js).

```
<script src="path/to/url.js"></script>
<script src="your-js.js"></script>
```

Then you can do:

```
var token = Url.queryString("s");
var tokenB = Url.queryString("_sft_category");
```

And that's it.

Note that instead of calling `parent()` multiple times, you can use the `closest()` method:

```
$('a[data-filter-value="' + attribuB + '"]')
   .closest("<your_container>")
   .find(".dropdown-toggle")
   .html(tokenB)
   .append(' <span class="caret"></span>')
   ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your location.href probably doesn't contain your `longString`. If you split the `href` using a string that's not present in `href`, you're left with an array with only 1 string, so you cannot get the [1] element.
It all depends on what your `token` variable is....

You've used a '?' character twice, which is incorrect. 
I'd use

```
var tokenB = document.location.href.split('_sft_category=')[1].match(/[a-z0-9]+/);
```

to get the desired value, as `_sft_category=` will probably only occur once in location.href and you should then be able to split the href into an array of 2.
Saves you 2 lines of code ;) ...

Comment: I'm trying to get the last string after longString, if I use [0] I would get the first

Comment: well, that just depends on what 'token' is. Why not just use '?_sft_category=' for longstring? I'd say that part will only occur once in your href...

Comment: sorry, i did not insert the var where I am defining token, question updated